# Is there any Better way for Routing the page

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to Angular js. I have created simple login page. My code is working perfectly. But I want it to `route` the page , when I login. I went through some of the blog , but I din't got the better approach.

I have created a plunker. Please check it out here.

https://plnkr.co/edit/9O5dHYZMKAqF07y7moVT

Answer (score 0):

Formerly known as Angular then as Angular 1.x is now called AngularJS. 
Notice it's one word :)

In order to change a route inside a controller. 
( I assume this is what you mean by question since I see some playing with the login information.)
You can use $location.

```
$location.path(path-to-where-you-wanna-go);
```

You also need to tell injector to use $location, so your complete controller would look like:

```
app.controller('credientials', function($scope, $location, authentication) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  $scope.cred = 'admin/123';

  $scope.templates =
                [
                    { url: 'login.html' },
                    { url: 'practice.html'}
                ];
                    $scope.template = $scope.templates[0];
                    $scope.loginform = function (username, password) {
                if ( $scope.username === 'admin' && $scope.password === '123') {
                    authentication.isAuthenticated = true;
                    $scope.template = $scope.templates[1];
                    $scope.user = username;
                    $scope.info = authentication.isAuthenticated;
                    $location.path( "/practice" );
                } else {
                    $scope.error = "Invalid username and password";
                }
              };
});
```

Assuming you wanna go to /practice route. Note, that you do lack the template and controllers for outer routes. Without it, it won't work.

Comment: Thank you. How should i call the path in html??

Comment: You can bind a function to the $scope and to the UI, for example with ng-click on some button. And in that function call $location.path same like above. Or you can leverage the fact that HTML supports URL change trough hyperlinks. <a href="FullPathOfYourNewLocation"></a>
Keep in mind that unlike with $location HTML doesn't know your app locations and you need to input the entire URL.